# AngularJS data undefined after form submiting

Tags: angularjs

I have a simple form:

```
<form ng-cloak class="form-horizontal" name="regForm" ng-submit="submit()" novalidate>
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="pociFirstName" placeholder="First Name" name="pociFirstName" ng-model="poc.firstName" ng-required="true" ng-class="{red: regForm.pociFirstName.$invalid && (regForm.$submitted || regForm.pociFirstName.$touched)}" />
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="pociLastName" placeholder="Last Name" name="pociLastName" ng-model="poc.lastName" ng-required="true" ng-class="{red: regForm.pociLastName.$invalid && (regForm.$submitted || regForm.pociLastName.$touched)}" />
<input type="text" class="form-control" cc-number cc-eager-type cc-type="cardType" id="ccNum" placeholder="Card Number" name="ccNum" ng-model="card.number" ng-required="true" ng-class="{red: regForm.ccNum.$invalid && (regForm.$submitted || regForm.ccNum.$touched)}" ng-init="card.number=''"/>

....

<button class="btn btn-primary btn-payment" type="submit">Submit</button>   

</form>
```

then I have started part for the controller

```
$scope.regForm = {};
$scope.poc = {};
$scope.card = {};

$scope.submit = function () {

    console.log("Form submited");

    $scope.regForm = regForm;
    $scope.poc = regForm.poc;
    $scope.card = regForm.card;

    console.log("data: " + $scope.poc);
}
```

but after form submitting I'm not able to get data from the form - it came as `undefinied`.

Kind of simple thing to do but I have no idea where I have a mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be like this. you can access to `ng-model` value by `$scope`. so for access `ng-model="poc.firstName"` and `ng-model="poc.lastName"` just use `$scope.poc` and for access  `ng-model="card.number"` use `$scope.card`.

```
$scope.submit = function () {
  console.log("Form submited");
  console.log("data: " + $scope.poc);
}
```

Comment: And this is it. Thanks!